# Rectangular matrix

Tags: matrices

I know that if m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns of a matrix such that m is not equal to n then the matrix is called rectangular matrix. But I think a column matrix of dimension 2x1, 3x1 etc. and a row matrix of dimension 1x2, 1x3 etc. would also be rectangular matrices. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You are right.

It is matter of YOUR convenience how you understand "rectangular" matrix. See
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangularMatrix.html

It is OK to call column matrix or row matrix as "rectangular" matrix.

> Don’t say 'reflected acoustic wave', say 'echo'. Forget all that
>   `local minima'. Just say there's a 'bubble' caught in the crystal and
>   you have to shake it - Richard Feynman

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is indeed correct. The only real difference is how we think of these objects. A rectangular matrix is a matrix and hence is a mapping between vector spaces. A vector is an object in a vector space but as a matrix (rectangular as you point out) it can also be thought of as a mapping as well. When we are looking at object in vector spaces we call them vectors so as to specify in which way we are interpreting them at the time.

Similarly numbers are just 1x1 matrices, again we don't ever really think of them as this and so we don't call them square matrices, but technically we could.

Comment: You're welcome :)